# How does this variable declaration works in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, hex

```
i = 0x0800
```

What I understand here is that  0x0800 is a hexadecimal number where '0x' denotes the hex type and the following number '0800' is a 2 byte hexadecimal number. On assigning it to a variable 'i', when its type is checked  I got this error

```
>>> type(i)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Here I make out that 'i' is suppose to be an int object. I got more confused when I tried this

```
>>> print i
2048
```

What is '2048' exactly .. Can anyone throw some light here ?

Comment: You assigned something to `type`, it is **not** the built-in function.

Comment: As to how does `i = 0x0800` work, see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`i` is an integer, but you *redefined `type`*:

```
>>> i = 0x0800
>>> i
2048
>>> type(i)
<type 'int'>
>>> type = 42
>>> type(i)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> del type
>>> type(i)
<type 'int'>
```

Note the `type = 42` line; I created a new global name `type` and that is found before the built-in. You could also use `import __builtin__; __builtin__.type(i)` in Python 2, or `import builtins; builtins.type(i)` in Python 3 to access the original built-in `type()` function:

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> type = 42
>>> __builtin__.type(type)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(type)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> del type
>>> type(type)
<type 'type'>
```

The `0x` notation is just one of several ways of specifying an integer literal. You are still producing a regular integer, only the *syntax* for how you define the value differs here. All of the following notations produce the exact same integer value:

```
0x0800          # hexadecimal
0o04000         # octal, Python 2 also accepts 0400
0b100000000000  # binary
2048            # decimal
```

See the [*Integer Literals* reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals).

Comment: My Bad .. Got it ... Thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

I'll quickly put the answer that I figured out ....

i = 0x0800 will assign an int equivalent of the hexadecimal number (0800) to i.

So  if we go down to pieces this looks like

```
 >>> i
 2048
 >>> 
 >>> (pow(16,3) * 0) + ( pow(16,2) * 8 ) + (pow (16,1) * 0 ) + (pow(16,0) * 0)
 2048
```